# MobileFirst server error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Trying to diagnose a MobileFirst server error. v6.3, Liberty, Windows.

We have two supposedly identical servers, one is fine, one fails.

Symptom: server starts but console reports a server error when trying to populate the initial list of runtimes. Investigating further we see an attempt to call an admin service.

So we attempt to call that service directly from a browser. On the working server we see

```
{"projects":
 [{"name":"DM","link":"https://shqomfas01.dm.gov.ae:9443/wladmin/management- apis/1.0/runtimes/DM","numberOfAdapters":16,
 "numberOfApplications":2,"synchronizationStatus":"ok",
 "numberOfActiveDevices":0,"numberOfDecommissionedDevices":0,
 "running":true}],"productVersion":"6.3.0.00-20141127-1357"}
```

On the other server we get an error response and see these exceptions in the logs.

```
[6/16/15 11:42:23:284 GST] 000000ec RuntimeServic > RuntimeService getAllRuntimes ENTRY uri=https://shqomfas02.dm.gov.ae:9443/wladmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/ securityContext=org.apache.wink.server.internal.contexts.SecurityContextImpl_83263026 httpRequest={Loc=en_US, Locs=(en_US,), User=admin, RemoteUser=admin} null
[6/16/15 11:42:23:284 GST] 000000ec SystemErr     R   1832175  WorklightManagementPU-oracle  INFO   [LargeThreadPool-thread-164] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
[6/16/15 11:42:23:284 GST] 000000ec SystemErr     R   1832175  WorklightManagementPU-oracle  INFO   [LargeThreadPool-thread-164] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.OracleDictionary".
[6/16/15 11:42:23:331 GST] 000000ec LibertyRuntim I   Establishing REST connection to service:jmx:rest://localhost:9443/IBMJMXConnectorREST
[6/16/15 11:42:24:097 GST] 000000ec RuntimeServic > ResponseUtil error ENTRY
[6/16/15 11:42:24:112 GST] 000000ec RuntimeServic E   FWLSE3000E: A server error was detected.
                                 com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.util.exceptions.SystemException: FWLSE3000E: A server error was detected.
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RuntimeService.addMBeanProperties(RuntimeService.java:1112)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RuntimeService.getAllRuntimes(RuntimeService.java:306)
```

...

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CWWKX0214E: An unexpected Throwable object was returned from the server.
    at com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.client.rest.internal.RESTMBeanServerConnection.getAttribute(RESTMBeanServerConnection.java:758)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy$GetHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy163.getDevicesSummary(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RuntimeService$RuntimeMBeanProperties.<init>(RuntimeService.java:1021)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RuntimeService$3.call(RuntimeService.java:1050)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RuntimeService$3.call(RuntimeService.java:1048)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.util.RuntimeMBeanRoutingCaller.call(RuntimeMBeanRoutingCaller.java:66)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RuntimeService.addMBeanProperties(RuntimeService.java:1045)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Runtime synchronization failed. Cannot get devices summary from runtime
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.rethrow(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.rethrowMaybeMBeanException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
```

suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

We were seeing this issue today.  We had recently made configuration changes to the server.xml file, and we received the "Server ERROR" message after login to the Worklight Console.

Reinstalling the runtime fixed our issue.